# Firestore: Query Single Attribute Across all Documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following structure in a Firestore collection. The "ranks" collection is updated with documents named after the timestamps. In each document, I have the same fields and values. How can I query all documents for a specific field without parsing the entire document? I.e. I want all values in all documents where field is "aave"?

I am new to Firestore and I've been trying this for several weeks now. I tried limiting with `where` and considered using sub collection group queries but in my case data is not stored in sub collections. Sorry, for not being able to provide more context, since I couldn't get much closer.

[image]

Comment: How many distinct values are you approximately expecting? How fast do you need the query to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries select specific values, or ranges of values, of a known field. There is no support for dynamic field names in a query in Firestore.

But if you want to get all documents where the field `aave` exists/has any value, you can make use of the fact that in the [sort order of values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#value_type_ordering) they always start with `null`. So to get all documents where the field `aave` exists/has any value, you could do:

```
firebase.firebase().collection("ranks").where("aave", ">=", null)
```

Comment: My main limitation is having to retrieve the entire document whereas, I only need the field `aave`. I decided to resolve this by restructuring the database. Thanks very much for your answer.